# Angular & typescript: using function argument as a type

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following type

```
export type SomeToken<K extends string, V = any> = {
    [key in K]: V;
} & {
    created_at: Date;
    created_by_user: string;
};
```

usually `K` is a single string (e.g. `K = 'token_a'`). These tokens are loaded with the following method

```
public getToken<TokenId extends string>(token_id: string): Observable<SomeToken<TokenId>> {
    return this.http.get<SomeToken<TokenId>>(ENDPOINT_URL + '/' + token_id);
}
```

To call `getToken` I need to do something like `getToken<'token_id'>('token_id')`. `token_id` is repeated twice. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: [Please ask a single question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366).  Which one of those two questions is primary? I assume it's the first one.  If so, then the solution is to make `token_id` have the generic type instead of `string`, like `public getToken<T extends string>(token_id: T): Observable<SomeToken<T>> {}` .  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I've removed the second question. And yes, your answer is what I need, please write it up as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there's no relationship between the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` (renamed from `TokenId`) and the type of the `token_id` parameter, which is just `string`... so if you want both to be the same type you need to specify it twice.

If, instead, you want the compiler to *infer* `T`  from the value you pass in as the `token_id` parameter, you need to give `token_id` the type `T`:

```
public getToken<T extends string>(token_id: T): Observable<SomeToken<T>> {
    return this.http.get<SomeToken<T>>(ENDPOINT_URL + '/' + token_id);
}
```

Then things work as desired:

```
const t = new WhateverYourClassNameIs().getToken("token_id");
// const t: Observable<SomeToken<"token_id", any>>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0zgF84AzKCEOAcigA8ArdOgbgChPNHJY4MAJ5gSAZRqYAKhADWmAHYAeANJxeMRQBN0cdDCjAFAcwA0cAGpwAvHDwKhAPhuJOcd3ADa8oXCNwVAF0ALksucgAyVw84AGMoTDxNLQB9JNCAESTMLhj4xOSU1CEUgFcsKFD9QxNwrliIBX04AFEAOQyABWQASTapFIBVACUAGRcAIhAjUFKQAFoEsGotUtjgIkx53jxwYnmAdwhSwi151C2FYFjMCe5Ywjx0XQAxCAhojwALGBgwUKQxkwMCUUkcAApGKF7EIAJTQhxkFwKE6EACEXDcHjApSI1zgQJgMnkyik6kYmgUOj0BiMxghMDkihSwC0oSk8JQGGw+E2SgkIGkTNJjmcCCxMXcCRgpSgCkEX2A6AAdD8-srCfzJMTFKDReD2l1ev0hmM4ABqegAejoFsEwpZWlhuQ8pE4bs4DSa8AoyMwBzgbwg4NhGuBOoU4ImjJJjomzs4VqtcUazQooTQFV5xC1gojSmjDtZE3MMNF3E4QA)